# MySQL database freezing after 'use'

Tags: mysql, backup

I recently made a rather stupid mistake and corrupt my Ubuntu installation.  To resolve it, I booted with a live cd and copied the database files over.  However, now I have copied the folders from the old installation into the new one, whenever I type "use database_name" it just freezes on this:

```
mysql> use my_database_name;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
```

And then freezes without giving the terminal.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On the first "use" command after login, MySQL scans database, tables and columns name for auto completion. If you have many db, tables it could take a while.

To avoid that, launch your client with the -A option (or --no-auto-rehash)

```
mysql -uroot -p -A
```

You could also add the **disable_auto_rehash** variable in your **my.cnf** (in the [mysql] section) if you want to disable it completely. This change does not require a reboot (it is a client, not server, variable).

Comment: can "a while" be more than a day for a ~2.5GiB database, or is that unreasonably long?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the "Reading table information" was taking an unreasonable amount of time. When I ran `mysql -e 'show processlist'` I discovered that the process that was "hanging" was "Waiting for table metadata lock". This made some sort of sense as I had a long-running query of the form `create table from select ...` running elsewhere, so on one level I could understand that until that new table was finished being created, the metadata about tables would not be available. (I guess it would be preferable if auto-complete scan just omitted any "incomplete" tables from the meta data query if this were possible.)

Comment: I faced a similar issue.. what does `Waiting for table metadata lock` means?

Comment: I'm not a MySQL internal guru, but looks like a reasonable explanation [here](https://lxadm.com/MySQL:_avoiding_%22Waiting_for_table_metadata_lock%22_when_executing_%22ALTER_TABLE%22). Basically it wants to alter meta data about a table, i.e. catalog information (not content) but that meta data is locked because of some other process.

Answer (score 1):

> When you **copy entire database from other system:**
>
> **/var/lib/mysql/***
>
> You may **chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/*** and start service again.
>
> ☝ this solved my problem

Comment: Welcome to DBA Stack Exchange! You've formatted this as a quote; if you really got this solution from elsewhere, [you must provide the source](/help/referencing). If not, please remove the formatting.